# Cannot retrieve text from textfield that has data from SQL Server database

Tags: java, html, sql-server, database, jdbc

i an creating a java website were i save stories in a database, the story get created, revised then exported.
To Revise the story, i have retrieved it from the database and fill it in editable HTML textfields and textareas, so it can be edited, but am having a problem saving this edited (Revised) version in the database again.
PS - I cannot replace the original story

When i try "request.getParameter" from the textfields and text areas- It shows "Null"

I have included my codes, i am fairly new to java, so can some please guide me as to how to correct my code.

Thank you in advance.

```
<tr>
    <td width="15%" height="25"  align="left"><font face="Calibri" color="#333333">Heading</font></td>
    <td width="90%" height="25"  colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Heading" size="71" value="<%=rs.getString("Heading")%>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="15%" height="25"><font face="Calibri" color="#333333">Category</font></td>
    <td width="90%" height="25" colspan="3"><font face="Calibri" color="#333333"><input type="text" name="Category" value="<%=rs.getString("Category")%>"></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"><textarea name="Story" rows="30" cols="108" style=" font-family: Calibri"><%= rs.getString("Story")%></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="25" colspan="4" align="center">
        <% out.println("<A href=Revised_Story_Val.jsp?Story_ID="+test+">Send to Export Queue</a>"); %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the code from the next page (Revised_Story_Val) that updates the database.

```
out.println ("Test - Connected");

String ID = request.getParameter("Story_ID");
String heading = request.getParameter("Heading");
String cat = request.getParameter("Category");
String story = request.getParameter("Story");
String fname =(String)session.getAttribute("fname");     
String lname =(String)session.getAttribute("lname");  

out.println ("Test - " + ID); //Gives correct data
out.println ("Test - " + heading); // gives NULL
```

If there is any alternate method of what i have described above, kindly help me out.

Comment: The fields should be inside an html form. You shouldn't get to the next page using a link, but by using the form submit button. The form action should be the URL of the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place your fields inside a form and use **input** **type="submit"** to submit data. I have also added a hidden field which holds the ID of story (instead of test):

```
  <from action="Revised_Story_Val.jsp" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td width="15%" height="25"  align="left"><font face="Calibri" color="#333333">Heading</font></td>
        <td width="90%" height="25"  colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Heading" size="71" value="<%=rs.getString("Heading")%>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="15%" height="25"><font face="Calibri" color="#333333">Category</font></td>
        <td width="90%" height="25" colspan="3"><font face="Calibri" color="#333333"><input type="text" name="Category" value="<%=rs.getString("Category")%>"></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><textarea name="Story" rows="30" cols="108" style=" font-family: Calibri"><%= rs.getString("Story")%></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="25" colspan="4" align="center">
            <input type="hidden" name="Story_ID=" value="<%=rs.getString("id")%>">
            <input type="submit" value="Send to Export Queue">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can check the answer as the accepted solution in left side (under the score of answer)